# Stuck with a regular expresion

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

I have the following in Javascript and are trying to do this in apex but having issues

```
.replace(/\s+/g, '-') // Replace spaces with -
.replace(/&/g, '-and-') // Replace & with 'and'
.replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '') // Remove all non-word chars
.replace(/\--+/g, '-') // Replace multiple - with single -
.replace(/^-+/, '') // Trim - from start of text
.replace(/-+$/, ''); // Trim - from end of text
```

Apex

```
.replaceAll('  +', '-') // Replace spaces with -
.replaceAll('[&]', '-and-') // Replace & with 'and'
.replaceALL('[^\w-]', '') // Remove all non-word chars
.replaceAll('-+', '-') // Replace multiple - with single -
.replace('[^-+]', '') // Trim - from start of text
.replace('[-+$]', '') // Trim - from end of text
```

The `.replaceALL('[^\w-]'` gives me an error:
Illegal character sequence `\w`' in string literal

`.replace('[^-+]', '')` does not seem to remove the first -

The `.replace('[-+$]', '')`  does not seem to remove the last -
If I use `.replaceAll('[-+$]', '')` it removes all the -

The rest I got working but do not understand these issues since if been trying to understand how to write the correct regex.

Comment: You have to remember that Apex has its own backslash handling, so you must encode the backslash. To do `\w` enter `\\w`.

Comment: Then remember that `[]` character classes interpret `-` differently depending where it appears since it can indicate a character range. Try using `[^+-]` instead.

Comment: Escape all the \ characters with more \ characters. Like: `String input = 'Some text with spaces & and other chars'; // The input string
String output = input
.replaceAll('\\s+', '-') // Replace spaces with -
.replaceAll('&', '-and-') // Replace & with 'and'
.replaceAll('[^\\w-]+', '') // Remove all non-word chars
.replaceAll('-{2,}', '-') // Replace multiple - with single -
.replaceFirst('^-+', '') // Trim - from start of text
.replaceFirst('-+$', ''); // Trim - from end of text
System.debug(output); // Print the output`

Comment: You have incorrectly removed square brackets for character classes in a couple of the substitutions.

Comment: I've downvoted this because you opted to delete the previous iteration of your question rather than try to improve it. It also seems like you did not take my advice of learning more about regex (enclosing everything inside of `[]` is not the right approach. That has a specific meaning in regex and you really ought to learn _why_ that caused things to not work). Also, the `Illegal character sequence \w' in string literal` should have been an easy error to research.

Comment: @DerekF Thank you for your explanation. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape all the \ characters with more \ characters.

Like:

```
String input = 'Some text with spaces & and other chars'; 
String output = input.replaceAll('\\s+', '-') // Replace spaces with - 
                     .replaceAll('&', '-and-') // Replace & with 'and' 
                     .replaceAll('[^\\w-]+', '') // Remove all non-word chars 
                     .replaceAll('-{2,}', '-') // Replace multiple - with single - 
                     .replaceFirst('^-+', '') // Trim - from start of text 
                     .replaceFirst('-+$', ''); // Trim - from end of text 
System.debug(output);
```

Output Is: **Some-text-with-spaces-and-and-other-chars**

Comment: This doesn't explain why you must escape them but also incorrectly changed some character classes into character sequences (e.g. `[^-+]` became `^-+` instead of being `[^+-]`).

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that Apex has its own backslash handling, so you must encode/escape the backslash. To do `\w` enter `\\w`, for example.

Remember too that `[]` character classes interpret `-` differently depending where it appears since it can indicate a character range. Try using `[^+-]` instead (since a `-` at the end of the character choices cannot be interpreted as defining a range, but rather a single character option).